# What do I have to do in CMD.EXE and/or PowerShell to specify a file (-o) with umlaut-characters when decrypting a file with gpg?

Tags: gnupg, encoding, powershell, cmd.exe

In cmd.exe and PowerShell, I am able to encrypt a file into a file whose filename contains umlaut-characters:

```
gpg -c --batch --yes --passphrase "one two three" -o bärlauch.gpg    data.txt
```

This produces a file named `bärlauch.gpg`, as intended.

However, if I want to decrypt the content of `bärlauch.gpg` to `bärlauch.txt`:

```
gpg -d --batch --yes --passphrase "one two three" -o bärlauch.txt bärlauch.gpg
```

it creates a file `b�rlauch.txt`.

The content of `b�rlauch.txt` is correctly decrypted, however, I'd like the filename to be `bärlauch.txt`.

I experience this behavior in both, cmd.exe and PowerShell.

In cmd.exe, I tried `chcp 65001`, `chcp 1252` and `chcp 437`, yet without any noticable effect.

What setting to I have to change so that I can decrypt a file into a filename with umlaut-characters?

The "strange" character is also displayed in Explorer:[image]

**Trying `--enable-special-filename`**

When trying the command line option `--enable-special-filename`, I get the same result.

```
gpg -c --batch --yes --passphrase "one two three" --enable-special-filenames -o bärlauch.gpg data.txt
gpg -d --batch --yes --passphrase "one two three" --enable-special-filenames -o bärlauch.txt bärlauch.gpg
```

**Trying `--use-embedded-filename`**

When trying with `--use-embedded-filename`, I still get the same result.
(I had to change the name of the unencrypted file from `data.txt` to `bärlauch.txt`, as per following sequence):

```
gpg -c --batch --yes --passphrase "one two three" --use-embedded-filename  -o bärlauch.gpg bärlauch.txt
gpg -d --batch --yes --passphrase "one two three" --use-embedded-filename                  bärlauch.gpg
```

Comment: What is the binary code for the `�` character? Is it also displayed this way in Explorer?

Comment: @harrymc: yes, see my attached screenshot in the edited questino

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT neither `--enable-special-filenames` nor `--use-embedded-filename` made a difference.

Comment: What version of GPG are you using? Consider running the latest version if you are not in case it's a GPG bug with the version you are using that creates the output with that file name. If you can get cmd or powershell to rename with the original file name, you can likely put logic around the process to rename if to match the original file name post decryption if the file name does not match. I know that'd be a workaround but possibly doable if that'd suffice and you confirm it's a GPG bug which you cannot correct with a different version.

Comment: Saw this: **https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118145/gpg-2-0-command-line-option-to-create-utf-8-data** but I don't know if it's still current.

Comment: This works for me with **[`chcp 437`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsBcl.png)**

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe So, I suspect it is because of my version. I have *2.25*. Is yours newer?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Is 2.2.19, take a **[look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUop9.png)**